# How do I parse the uploaded text with PHP

Tags: php, android

I am currently writing an android app which uploads specific text to a web server for data collection, I'm a complete noob when it comes to php and I would like an example of how I parse the given data on the server to save it to a file on the server.

```
try {
  // write to the stream
  StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
  String numData = URLEncoder.encode("phoneId", "UTF-8") + "="
          + URLEncoder.encode(mynumber, "UTF-8");
  String emailData = URLEncoder.encode("primaryEmail", "UTF-8") + "="
          + URLEncoder.encode(primaryEmail, "UTF-8");
  String passData = URLEncoder.encode("phoneModel", "UTF-8") + "="
          + URLEncoder.encode(phoneModel, "UTF-8");

  data.append(numData).append("&").append(emailData).append("&").append(phoneData);

  wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
  wr.write(data.toString());
  wr.flush();

  // read the result from the server
  rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
  Log.e("URL INVALID:", "The url given, " + urlString + ", is invalid.");
  return;
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
} finally {
  // close the connection, set all objects to null
  connect.disconnect();
  rd = null;
  sb = null;
  wr = null;
  connect = null;
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to parse from it? You have the text on the server side if you sent it. And now? There is the text. What do you want to know?

Comment: How do I have the php file show the data that has been uploaded?

Comment: By outputting it again, I'd say. Don't get this wrong: but what is the point of asking that here? Go and start reading a short introduction into php. You have to anyway. It will answer all typical beginner questions and help you set things up. Will take you a few minutes and you are ready to make your first script. Go!

Comment: side note - is `String passData` / `.append(phoneData)` a copy/paste error?

Comment: it looks like you are sending your data as url params, so have you tried echoing `$_GET['phoneId']`/ `$_GET['primaryEmail']`/ `$_GET['phoneModel']` in your php?

Comment: @arkascha I will do that, Sean no this is not an error, Sean I will look into PHP and echoing the data.